# Console command redirect to nothing

Tags: console, redirection

Is there a way to redirect Windows console commands to nothing\null?

A regular redirection might look like:

```
prog.exe > a.txt
```

However in my case I would like to redirect the output so that it will not be written or displayed anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Absolutely!

This directs standard output to nul:

```
prog.exe >nul
```

This directs errors to nul:

```
prog.exe 2>nul
```

This directs both to nul:

```
prog.exe >nul 2>nul
```

Comment: snazzy. this should let me clean up those scripts where i generate a temporary text file to hide output cause i didn't know better ;)